# How to print the file names from which I grep some lines

Tags: bash, terminal, grep

I'm trying to get some lines from several json files using the following code:

```
cat $(find ./*/*/folderA/*DTI*.json) | grep -i -E '(phaseencodingdirection|phaseencodingaxis)' > phase_direction
```

It worked! the problem is that I don't know which line comes from which file

With this `find ./*/*/preprocessing/*DTI*.json -type f -printf "%f\n"` I can print those names, but they appear at the end and not in order with their respective *phaseencodingdirection|phaseencodingaxis* extracted lines.

I don't know how to combine those lines of code to print the file's name from which the line was extracted and their respective extracted lines!?

Could you help me?

Comment: How about `grep -H`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the problem is that I don't know which line comes from which file

Well no, you don't, because you have concatenated the contents of all the files into a single stream.  If you want to be able to identify at the point of pattern matching which file each line comes from then you have to give that information to `grep` in the first place.  Like this, for example:

```
find ./*/*/folderA/*DTI*.json |
        xargs grep -i -E -H '(phaseencodingdirection|phaseencodingaxis)' > phase_direction
```

The `xargs` program converts lines read from its standard input into arguments to the specified command (`grep` in this case).  The `-H` option to `grep` causes it to list the filename of each match along with the matching line itself.

Alternatively, this variation on the same thing is a little simpler, and closer in some senses to the original:

```
grep -i -E -H '(phaseencodingdirection|phaseencodingaxis)' \
    $(find ./*/*/folderA/*DTI*.json) > phase_direction
```

That takes `xargs` out of the picture, and moves the command substitution directly to the argument list of `grep`.

But now observe that if the pattern `./*/*/folderA/*DTI*.json` does not match any directories then `find` isn't actually doing anything useful for you.  There is then no directory recursion to be done, and you haven't specified any tests, so the command substitution will simply expand to all the paths that match the pattern, just like the pattern would do if expanded *without* `find`.  Thus, this is probably best of all:

```
grep -i -E -H '(phaseencodingdirection|phaseencodingaxis)' \
    ./*/*/folderA/*DTI*.json > phase_direction
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the filenames as arguments to `grep` rather than `cat`.

```
grep -i -H -E '(phaseencodingdirection|phaseencodingaxis)' $(find ./*/*/folderA/*DTI*.json) > phase_direction
```

The `-H` option forces `grep` to incliude filenames in the output even if there's only one file.

But since your arguments to `find` are filenames, not directories to search recursively, there's no need to use it at all. Just pass the wildcard directly to `grep`. There's also no need to begin with `./`. Any non-absolute pathname is interpreted relative to the current directory.

```
grep -i -H -E '(phaseencodingdirection|phaseencodingaxis)' */*/folderA/*DTI*.json > phase_direction
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use recursive `grep`:

```sh
grep -iER 'phaseencodingdirection|phaseencodingaxis' --include=*DTI*.json */*/folderA
```